# Signing and aligning APK Step in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, jarsigner, azure-pipelines

I try to run my Signing and aligning APK Step on my Mac Build Server but, when I run it I get an following error...

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
Return code: 1

Below, I put my screenshot with configuration :

[image]

I am sure that the problem is explicitly with this step, because when I disable Sing the APK build succeeds.
Is something wrong with my Keystone File Path?

I would like to add, that project is in Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The task will assume that it's located here: `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jarsigner`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/3dfc1a5bb7de7d2d91b3b9b5c45036f6028db4ba/Tasks/AndroidSigning/androidsigning.ts#L28). if it isn't, the task will fail. There is no extended checking around any of the code it seems.

Ensure that for your build agent user the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and pointing to the right folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you suggested, the problem was with environment variable. From some reasons there wasn't JAVA_HOME on my Mac build server.